# How to selectively restore OS X?

Tags: macos, restore

Recently, it has come to my attention that as a programmer, I messed around too much with system files, (bash profile, homebrew .pc files, unlinked libraries for C++, messing something up really badly in trying to make fish shell to work with RBENV for Ruby on Rails training.)

Now, I could go ahead and reinstall OS X El Capitan and reinstall all the programs I have from scratch. But I really do not want to go through the hassle of having to find all the serials (some of which all I have is the receipt, and I don't want to go through customer service for 20 programs and get the serials)

What I do want to do is be able to say, have a Time Machine backup, and to reinstall a fresh copy of El Capitan (fix all those issues that are so far under the hood a 2 year CS major has no idea what he is dealing with), and selectively restore from an external copy of my old set up, say, Applications, Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST. My understanding is that using a built in Apple program called Migration Assistant, I can selectively restore these folders

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to restore just the programs from Applications without having to authenticate them again?
2. If an application stores various things in other folders, is there any way to figure out where these files are stored through a system scan or something similar?

P.S. I have seen a product called Carbon Copy Cloner. Does anyone have any experience with this product? Can the trial version accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Hello friend its very eary to do this , just follow me .......
While your backup disk is connected, click the Time Machine icon in the Dock and the Time Machine restore interface appears. You can literally see your windows as they appeared "back in time." Note: If you use FileVault, you cannot browse for individual items in your Home folder. However, you can restore all files and folders by using the Restore System from Backup feature of the Mac OS X Installer.
You can use the timeline on the right side of the window to reach a certain point back in time (the timeline shows the times of all backups on your backup disk). If you don’t know exactly when you deleted or changed a file, you can use the back arrow to let Time Machine automatically travel through time to show you when that folder last changed.

You can also perform a Spotlight search in the Time Machine Finder Window search field to find a file. Simply type the Spotlight search field and use the back arrow to have Time Machine search through your backups to find what you are looking for.

Before you restore a file, you can also use Quick Look to preview a file to make sure its the one you want. Highlight the file and press the Space Bar to bring up a preview.

To restore, select the file/folder and click the "Restore" button. The file will automatically be copied to the desktop or appropriate folder.  If the file you are restoring has another file in the same location with the same name, you will be prompted to choose which file to keep or keep both.

Answer (score 0):

For applications which are installed individually (not through the AppStore), there is no backup software which would "sandbox" individual applications and allow selective backup/restore, so you can do it only manually.

> Is it possible to restore just the programs from Applications without having to authenticate them again?

It depends solely on each application itself. Mind that generally authors/vendors of commercial applications, if they employ an authentication process, they possibly take measures to make the application transfer between machines as difficult as possible.

> If an application stores various things in other folders, is there any way to figure out where these files are stored through a system scan or something similar?

You might try using `fs_usage` to trace file access when application starts or verifies the licence, but the task will likely get overwhelming (especially if you didn't have two machines: one for reference and a new one for verification).

> Can the trial version [of Carbon Copy Cloner] accomplish what I want?

Not automatically. CCC is a good backup program allowing you to:

- restore your system to a recent state (which you want to avoid in the first place);
- to boot your system from the external media to a backed up system state.

The latter could mitigate the problem of having a machine with the known good state to copy the configuration from, alongside the newly created one. You can use it as a source for your manual migration tasks.

*I am not sure however, if you would manage to restore everything manually during the 30-day trial period.*